# How to recognize object with number of amount that are increasing dynamically

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Let's say I have a set of images and I'm going to use these images to identify people who are coming to the office. Then I build my own face recognition and I train the ANN to recognize faces. But a month later, there's a new employee, should I re-train the ANN (entirely)? Is there any 'dynamic technique', so I can just train the new one not the whole images?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem. By training the ANN, the system learns a pattern. Why don't you use a database where you store the persons represented by pictures and assign pattern descriptions to them? This way, when you train the ANN to recognize a pattern, you will store it associated to the person and when you want the system to be able to determine whose picture is shown, just use the separate patterns to determine whose pattern resembles the picture the most.

If I were you, a pattern stored would be directly usable to initiate back the already trained ANN.

Comment: Ah I forgot to specify the NN, I'm thinking to use Backpropagation NN. And if I use the stored pattern to initiate back, and I train the new one, won't it change whole pattern before?

Comment: You need to have a one-to-one relation between pattern and person. A pattern would be a person's property. You should not override the patterns learned earlier. You should store the learned patterns separately.